# Custom Transaction implementation - Threading and Locks

Tags: c#, multithreading, transactions, locking, thread-safety

I'm doing some stuff with SQLite, and I want threads to block while I am in a "Transaction". Will the below code work correctly?

```
public class ThreadSafeSQLiteConnection 
{
    private readonly SQLiteConnection connection;
    public static object TRANSACTION_LOCK = new Object();

    public void BeginTransaction() {
        Monitor.Enter(TRANSACTION_LOCK);
        connection.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public void Commit() {
        connection.Commit();
        Monitor.Exit(TRANSACTION_LOCK);
    }

    public void Rollback() {
        connection.Rollback();
        Monitor.Exit(TRANSACTION_LOCK);
    }
}
```

If I have a transaction open in this case, no threads can enter the `BeginTransaction` method correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the following code will work but it will misbehave when working with multiple connections since your locker instance is static and therefore shared by all instances. I dont see why you would want a statically synchronized locker instance since the sql transaction already provides the synchronization. So: just remove the static part from the transaction_lock and you're good to go!

Comment: @Groo - forgive me for not being a sql lite expert :) but isnt the SqlLite transaction there to protect from race conditions when concurrent connections are trying to write?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think this through. Yes, SQLite is thread safe for writing. I would, however, make the `TRANSACTION_LOCK` private in any case.